# RabbitMQ management plugin issue

Tags: unix, plugins, rabbitmq

I'm trying to install RabbitMQ management plugin but get the following in the console:

```
Error: {cannot_write_enabled_plugins_file,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins",
           eacces}
```

I use Ubuntu 12. On [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) page is told that The management plugin is included in the RabbitMQ distribution. To enable it, use rabbitmq-plugins:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

but the result you see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`?

P.S.: looks like a question for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have provided `777` permissions to the file and still you are not able to enable it, try changing umask to 0022 for user

```
sudo chfn -o umask=0022 <username>
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
chown rabbitmq.rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue for me had to do with [STIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Technical_Implementation_Guide). To override default permission setting when file created:

setfacl -d -m g::rwx /etc/rabbitmq

setfacl -d -m o::rwx /etc/rabbitmq

Answer (score -1):

Switch to `rabbitmq user` and then `enable` plugin like below:

```
$su - rabbitmq
$rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```